# RMSprop optimizer in model compiling section ,in keras does not work

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

i use tensorflow 2.1.0 and keras 2.2.4tf
when I want to compile my model[here is the piece of code I use]:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
              metrics=['acc'])
```

it gives this error :

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-09848482494e> in <module>
     30 
     31 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
---> 32               optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
     33               metrics=['acc'])
     34 

NameError: name 'optimizers' is not defined
```

but, I do not know what is the problem. if you may help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try calling:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
  metrics=['acc'])
```

Comment: `lr` is deprecated.
`
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=2e-5),
  metrics=['acc'])
`